# How to make a functional component with an optional function to be debounced?

Tags: reactjs

I have an `Input` component where i want to pass in an optional validation function which gonna be debounced to validate the input.

Right now i'm defining the debounced function in the upper scope to avoid calling it every time the component re-renders but that makes my component not reusable.

How can i define the debounced function as part of the component itself ?

I tried to return the function from `useState` but i was keep getting undefined so i guess you can't return functions from `useState` ?

This is a my [Input component](https://codesandbox.io/s/8z0yrkqo78) so far.

Answer (score 0):

From official doc of react:

> What do we pass to useState as an argument? The only argument to the useState() Hook is the initial state. Unlike with classes, the state doesn’t have to be an object. We can keep a number or a string if that’s all we need. In our example, we just want a number for how many times the user clicked, so pass 0 as initial state for our variable. (If we wanted to store two different values in state, we would call useState() twice.)

So, you can not return the function from `useState`. The easiest way to do that is create an helper function and import it into your component